# Recommended Reading for iPhone Core Animation

Tags: iphone, core-animation

Can anyone here recommend any good books for getting my head around Core animation?
I've been through the Apple docs and while I'm sure it's all there, I haven't been able to grok Core Animation yet... Is there an a good example I've missed? or some starting document I've overlooked?
If not are there any good books out there on Core Animation... the few hits I've gotten while looking on Amazon don't rate anything too high, mostly MacOSX little iphone.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In addition to the books suggested by Alex and nevan (of which I'd recommend Marcus Zarra and Matt Long's newer [Core Animation book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321617754), given its greater quantity of iPhone coverage), I taught a class on iPhone Core Animation recently.  The video for that class [can found on iTunes U](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-spring-2010/id407243032).  My class notes, with detailed coverage of Core Animation, can be downloaded [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/AdvancediPhoneApps.zip) (in VoodooPad format).

I also gave a presentation on Core Animation at the recent iPadDevCamp in Chicago, for which the slides and sample code can be found [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/05/03/my-core-animation-talk-ipaddevcamp-chicago).

Comment: The link to iTunes University is now a 500 with ugly error message. Apple mucking about with their URL's?

Comment: @Adam - It looks like all iTunes U links are returning errors now.  This must be a server-side error (I've reported it).  In the meantime, we're now listed in the main directory in iTunes, so you can search for "Advanced iPhone Development" to find the class.

Comment: Thanks, search worked (if you first go to the itunes U Directory - it fails if you do it from the itunes U main link, because Apple search is context-sensitive, sigh)

Answer (score 6):

[Core Animation: Simplified Animation Techniques for Mac and iPhone Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321617754) explains it nicely.

Answer (score 4):

I liked some of [this Pragmatic Programmer book](http://pragprog.com/titles/bdcora/core-animation-for-mac-os-x-and-the-iphone).