# Is there a way to produce animations beyond stacks of images in UIImage?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, animation

I'm fairly new to iOS development, and I was wondering: is there a way to produce animations on the iPhone besides creating a bunch of still images and animating them in a UIImageView?  What are the other methods for creating a moving animation on iOS?

Comment: refer this [document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html).It may helps you to create animation app

Comment: i want to create animation as try to make a cassette look like it is recording or playing.. i manage to create with uiimageview but i was inform that you can create it with core animation.is it possible to use core animation in iphone apps. and how to do it .. what kind of code should i use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has an entire framework called Core Animation that is built to help you make animations within your interface.  I recommend checking out the various resources listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907068/recommended-reading-for-iphone-core-animation) for learning how to use Core Animation in its various forms.

Answer (score 0):

Simple animations can be easily done by transforming views within the 
[UIView beginAnimations: context:] and [UIView commitAnimations].

For example, to scale the current view, you would :

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"auxviewclose" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
self.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.superview.frame.size.height-45, self.frame.size.width, 45);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```