# play animation on iphone game?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to do a simple game but full with animation in the start and the middle of the game.

my question is:
What is the best way to play the animations?
I am good with Adobe Flash and can do my animations on it.
can I benefit from it, or is there another way to do that.

thanks for all answers, but my main question is it efficient to play video instead of sequence of images, or is there a way to play the flash video, to like the image sequence with the volume.

Answer (score 1):

will suggest you to use the `CoreAnimation`  **framework** that have in-build animation support, most of the animations can be accomplished by `CoreAnimation`.

Here is the Apple tutorial guide to `CoreAnimation` .

[Core Animation Programming Guide: Introduction to Core Animation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[Recommended Reading for iPhone Core Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907068/recommended-reading-for-iphone-core-animation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cocs2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) framework for designing game with different animations.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about cut-scene animations or sprite animation? Video is definitely going to be more efficient than frame sequences for a cutscreen animation. You could build you animation and export to video from Flash if you are good with it. If your talking about sprite animations, as Anish said, [Cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) has really fast sprite sheet support. Here's a good intro:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d