# What do I have to study to make "Push Pop Press"-like animations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, animation

I read Al Gore's "Our choice" (by Push Pop Press) and I'd like to add similiar animations to my iPad app. What do I have to study? May you suggest me some useful guide/tutorial?

Best regards,
TonyMobike

Comment: They use an awful lot of Core Animation stuff :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommended Reading for iPhone Core Animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907068/recommended-reading-for-iphone-core-animation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all animations done there used [**Core Animation**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). Hope this helps...