# Animate custom UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a simple custom UIView (a rectangle) that is implemented with drawRect.

The view is drawn from two values; currentValue and maxValue

**From drawRect:**

The height of the rect represents how much currentValue is of maxValue:

```
if(currentValue > maxValue)
    currentValue = maxValue;

float scale = currentValue/maxValue;

//Draw the rect
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height-(self.bounds.size.height*scale));
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.size.height-(self.bounds.size.height*scale));
CGContextClosePath(context);

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextFillPath(context);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

I've setup a ViewController with a UISlider that changes the currentValue and each time it's changed setNeedsDisplay gets called. This part works just fine. The rect changes height when the slider is used, exactly as planned.

**My question is..** I would like this transition between heights to be animated. What's the best way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having UIView with custom drawing your can add `CAShapeLayer` object to your view's layer. `CAShapeLayer` class allows to specify path to draw and draw attributes - and also changes for those properties are easily animatable.

If your view is just a rect filled with solid color as in question your second option is either adjust view's frame or set appropriate affine transform to get required heights - both those properties are also easily animatable using animation methods in `UIView` class.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a simple UIView rect and changing the frame instead inside UIView animateWithDuration.. and then letting the Controller do all of it..

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want a simple shape that can be drawn by a Core Animation layer (like `CAShapeLayer` or `CAGradientLayer`), you should just use a Core Animation layer and a `CABasicAnimation` to animate the layer's frame.

If you plan to draw something more complex, and you want to animate changes to the shape, then  you need to do more work.  You need to give your object properties or instance variables to store the current and final values, and maybe to store the velocity of the value.  You need to create a `CADisplayLink` object and use it to drive calls to your animation method.  Your animation method should update the current value based on how much time has passed and then call `setNeedsDisplay`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to do this with Core Animation. The relevant docs are on Apple's [developer site](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). There is also a good source of links on Core Animation with iOS on this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907068/recommended-reading-for-iphone-core-animation).